# Can I stop Auto CheckOut in VSS on VS 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

I use VSS on VS 2005 on my office , VSS is not bad and get used to it now
But there are one problem there . when I try to edit or make write source
VS dectect change and check out my source automatically It's good It's OK 
but VS not only check my own source files VS check out the Project ! in where 
my source's there!

I want to know about there are any option to check out on my own sources...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the setting at VS Tools->Options->Environment-> Checked-in items - Editing.